# Elixir: how to make struct enumerable

Tags: struct, enumerable, elixir

I have a struct:

```
my_struct = %MyStruct{a: 1, b: 2}
```

how do I make it enumerable, so I can use the `Enum` methods on it?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Map.to_list(struct)` instead of `Enum.to_list`, since structs are just maps with a `__struct__` key.

Comment: cool, thanks. Though, I'd still like to know how to convert it to an Enumerable - just in case.

Comment: You could look here: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ca2ea6c0bd660d9a06a54a74d5784d7a552925bf/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2163

That's the implementation of Enumerable for Map. You could pretty easily implement that for your struct type to make it enumerable.

Comment: In upcoming versions we are going to support @derive, so you can get the Enumerable behaviour easily!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question and just wanted to add that (a few months after it was answered) [we now have `Map.from_struct/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#from_struct/1):

```
iex(10)> %MyStruct{a: 1, b: 2} |> Map.from_struct |> Enum.count
2
```